# Using KVO to track NSProgress

Tags: ios

I am using KVO to track the progress of a file that is being received:

```
-(void)session:(MCSession *)session didStartReceivingResourceWithName:(NSString *)resourceName fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withProgress:(NSProgress *)progress

{
NSLog(@"RECEIVING... %@ from peer: %@", progress, peerID);
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [progress addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"fractionCompleted"
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                   context:NULL];
});}
```

and

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
if (object == progress) {
    // Handle new fractionCompleted value
[progressBar setProgress:progress.fractionCompleted animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Fraction Complete: %@", [NSNumber numberWithDouble:progress.fractionCompleted]);
    return;
}

[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                     ofObject:object
                       change:change
                      context:context];
}
```

I would like to use this to update a UIprogressView...
But the code is crashing at this line and I don't get why:

```
[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                     ofObject:object
                       change:change
                      context:context];
```

EDIT:

This is the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:     '<ViewController1: 0x15b57000>: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was     received but not handled.
```

EDIT:

If I remove the super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath..., the app doesn't crash, but the NSLog(@"Fraction Complete: %@ always reports the value "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your superclass have observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: implemented?
You can do an if check on that:

```
if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:){
    NSLog(@"Yeah, I'm here matey!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Uh oh said the selector ghost");
}
```

Comment: The code you see in the question is the only code I have. If there is any other code I should add please provide it, thanks

Comment: Try get rid of the super observeValue... call.

Comment: Ok I did and the app doesn't crash any more but the fractioncompleted reported is always 0!! And I know it is not because I logged it with an NSTimer...

Comment: log out the change dictionary. Sorry, its hard to give you more advice since I dont know the libraries you're linking it against.

Comment: is it this??<NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> from peer: <MCPeerID: 0x1758b210 DisplayName = alessandro's iPod touch-593288>